# How to run Springboot application with Junit test with Docker File

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, dockerfile

Right now I have my Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

What if I want to run some junit test after I start the springboot application? I am using Maven for dependencies.

Where should I put those lines?

```
mvn test
mvn clean test
mvn clean compile test
```

Or what other commands should I use?

Comment: To run unit tests you should write unit tests which will be executed during. the build of your application before the application has been packaged into a jar file. This is usually done via `mvn clean test`. Put your unit tests into `src/test/java` and name them like `*Test.java`. If you have spring boot tests tests you should name them like `*IT.java` and will be run during the integration test phase which can be executed via `mvn clean verify`.  Furthermore you should read about the build life cycle https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Yes I have written my junit test in the correct directory. But I would like to know how to execute it in docker file

Comment: If you want to execute the test build, why are you starting the actual app? The tests can't depend on the app running, or the app wouldn't build, or am I missing something?

Comment: In the docker file either you only package your final application or you build inside a docker container...the question is: What would you like to do?

Comment: I am trying to push springboot application to travis ci, and run junit test on travis ci. so I need to define the command in docker file

Answer (score 3):

> **Premise: Even if the solution is oriented to your specifics it would be better to execute tests during target jar build phase**

To execute tests on your Dockerfile you can do one of the following:

1. copy also source files on Dockerfile and execute maven test commands. Doing this you can also build your target jar directly on the Container and also you need **maven** to be installed on the Container.
2. copy just the target jar file and use it to execute your tests you need to include test-classes on the target jar. ( See at [How can I include test classes into Maven jar and execute them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047637/how-can-i-include-test-classes-into-maven-jar-and-execute-them) ).

Regardless the way you choose, you can modify your entrypoint to execute multiple commands. You can do it basically in 2 ways:

1. **(a)** Creating a **bash script** that executes your commands( See at [Multiple commands on docker ENTRYPOINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121031/multiple-commands-on-docker-entrypoint) )
2. **(b)** Using **supervisord** ( See at [How to write a Dockerfile which I can start a service and run a shell and also accept arguments for the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691752/how-to-write-a-dockerfile-which-i-can-start-a-service-and-run-a-shell-and-also-a/34692197) ). This is a better solution in order to manage process related to the container life ( so the process with PID 1 ).

> **Example**

Let's suppose you choose to copy all source files ( option **1** ) and use a bash 
script ( option **1(a)** ) to do it.
Create the **command.sh** file as follow in order to attach container to Spring application process even if mvn test will be executed:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Execute Spring application
CMD="java -jar target/app.jar"
$CMD &
SERVICE_PID=$!

#Execute Tests
mvn test

#Wait for Spring execution
wait "$SERVICE_PID"
```

Your Dockerfile will look like follow:

```
#Start from maven docker image
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-alpine

#Copy all sources
COPY . .

#Build ( because you want to execute tests after the spring boot application is started you should disable test during build phase )
RUN mvn install

#Start container
COPY commands.sh /scripts/commands.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/scripts/commands.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/scripts/commands.sh"]
```

Comment: /scripts/commands.sh: line 11: wait: `': not a pid or valid job spec ？

Comment: This happens when you pass an empty argument to **wait** command. My issue on writing **command.sh** script missing the execution command `$CMD &`. I'm going to update the answer. Please retry.

Comment: Hi I still confused about the process. I looking for the following  achievement in the my docker file: mvn install, mvn test, and build the jar file, and I am also using this docker file to deploy it on aws elasticbean stalk as my applications backend server. How should my docker file look like? Thanks